# Java - How to stop an audioclip from another class

Tags: java, audio

Right now, i'm making an app that involves background audio, and with a couple of tips from other's questions and answers, i was able to make the audio work.

But right now, i'm trying to use a button in a  different class to stop an audioclip, that was instantiated in another class.

When i tested the prototype, all in the same class, it worked perfectly.

But in my main app, the "stop" button is in a different class (for good reason). I don't know if you'll want my code for the main app, but here's the prototype that i described: Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public class AudioPlay  {

    Clip clip;

   // Constructor
   public AudioPlay() {
        try {
            this.clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AudioPlay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

       JFrame f = new JFrame();

      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
      f.setSize(300, 200);
      f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      JButton button = new JButton("play");
        button.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                    
             playSound(0);                                     
           }
        });            

        JButton button2 = new JButton("stop");
        button2.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clip.stop();                          
           }
        });

        f.add(button);
        f.add(button2);
        f.setVisible(true);

   }

   public void playSound(int a){

       // Open an audio input stream.
       String[] sounds = new String[10];
       sounds[0]= "/audioplay/sounds/kk.wav";
       sounds[1]= "/audioplay/sounds/btn2.wav";
       try {
         URL url = this.getClass().getResource(sounds[a]);
         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);

         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();            

      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new AudioPlay();
   }
}
```

EDIT
here's the actual application
first of is the main class.............

```
public class Operator {
     static boolean player = false;
     Clip clip;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        Welcome on = new Welcome();
        on.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        on.setVisible(true);


    }

    public Operator() {
         try {
             this.clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Operator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }


     public void playBackground(int a){
    String[] sounds = new String[10];
       sounds[0]= "/operator/sounds/kk.wav";
       sounds[1]= "/operator/sounds/mnt5.wav";

      try {
         // Open an audio input stream.
          URL url= this.getClass().getResource(sounds[a]);

         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
         // Get a sound clip resource.

         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
      }
    }

    }
```

now next up, is where the sound begins to play

```
public class MainMenuTest extends javax.swing.JPanel {

   // this is for referencing 
    Operator sound = new Operator();
     static int course;
     static String courseName;

    //constructor  obviously..........
    public MainMenuTest() {

        initComponents();
    }





    public javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();



        sound.playBackground(0);
    /* writing this stop() action here below, causes the audio not to play, which is actually 
        what i want, but in another class 
        sound.clip.stop();
*/
        //most of the components are removed, they weren't really relevant


    }                                      


}
```

and lastly, the class in which the clip is stopped

```
public final class Options extends JPanel {
    // referencing stuff
    Operator sound = new Operator();
     private JButton Start;


    public Options() {
        initComponents();

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {


        Stop = new javax.swing.JButton("stop");



     Stop.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {
      public void stopActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           //this looks like the same stop() method  wrote before, but here, it ain't working
            sound.clip.stop();      


    }});                                    

    }                                           





}
```

Comment: Often this sort of problem occurs due to use of inappropriate references, when a coder tries to call the method of a new object, one completely distinct from the one that is actually playing the audio clip. Are you sure that you're passing in the correct Clip object into the class with the stop button's ActionListener with which to call `stop()` on?

Comment: You need to provide a reference to the AudioPlay instance to the button object (more precisely, to the listener that will act when the button is clicked).

Comment: As commented above this has little to do with audio then java object reference understanding. Read a java tutorial again and then tackle the issue.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yup, i made sure it's the correct clip object, the 'stop()' method only acts when its in the same class in which the 'playSound()' method is called.

Comment: I'm glad that you feel confident in this. As for me, if this were my bug, I would not trust my confidence until the bug were identified and solved. You may need to show more code to us. How much? Enough but not too much. :)

Comment: @SJuan76, i referenced only the clip field, shouldn't that be enough, i even tried making the clip static, but it still didn't work.

Comment: How did you make sure its the same object? Add a log/ system out in constructur of your objects to make sure your not making two. And print the hash code of the reference and the original to make sure they both point to same object.

Comment: okay, lemme just bring out the main code

Comment: You're currently showing the code that works, but not the code that doesn't work, correct? Hm

Comment: yeah, this code works, lemme just prepare the one that doesn't(it's kinda long)

Comment: As I suspended, your assumption was off base and you are in fact calling methods on a different instance. You would be doing yourself a favor to buy and read a book that focuses on OOPs as it applies to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As guessed, from comments your making extra new objects. Making a new object is like having a twin. Telling one twin to stop talking does not affect the other...

Operator sound = new Operator(); //in your code this should be done only once.

Do this only in the main mehtod and have other classes that need this to accept this in the constructor or use spring or other dependancy injection.

A simple sample:

```
package play;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AudioPlay  {

    private Clip clip;
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
   // Constructor
   public AudioPlay() {
        try {
            this.clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AudioPlay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
      f.setSize(300, 200);
      f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      JButton button = new JButton("play");
        button.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                    
             playSound(0);                                     
           }
        });            



        f.add(button);

        //f.setVisible(true);

   }

   public void stopSound() {
        clip.stop();   
        //clip.flush();
        clip.close();

    }

   public void playSound(int a){

       // Open an audio input stream.
       String[] sounds = new String[10];
       sounds[0]= "rs/Tr-3L_nA_sus_mf_D4.wav";
       sounds[1]= "rs/Tr-3L_nA_sus_mf_F#4.wav";
       File f = new File(sounds[a]);
       try {
         URL url = f.toURI().toURL();
         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);

         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();            

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println(e + " " + f);
      }

}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       AudioPlay ap = new AudioPlay();
       Other oth = new Other(ap, ap.f);
       ap.shw();
   }

   public void shw(){
       f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

//and

```
package play;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Other {

    private AudioPlay au;
    private JButton btnStop;

    public Other(AudioPlay aupl, JFrame f){
        this.au = aupl;
        btnStop = new JButton("Stop");
        f.add(btnStop);
        btnStop.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                au.stopSound();                       
           }


        });
    }

}
```

Here see how Other accepts a reference to the audio play class. And Audio play class is made only once (new).

FYI : not applicable to this but in general : we do want to make a new object if we need the old one or the old one was about somehting else. Example a Data transfer object where one was about an entity with id = 1 and the other has identity 2, and we are keeping track of them in a hashmap or other collection.

Also in web apps we have session , request scopes - but that is beyond this sample. For this sample the main thing is in a UI we generally want only 1 instance of every class, and different classes need same instance to talk to. One class cannot talk to instance one while talks to instance 2, and expect instance 1 to do something.

Comment: wow! thanks man this is great. I better brush up on my OOP then. But can i ask one last favor? Pls, can u create one more class that can play the sound again. (I tried out your guideline, and i can play the sound from another class, i just need one more class example to fully grasp this concept. would have up voted, but not enough rep points, sorry)

Comment: I think you can try that as a assignment, just move around code to a new function, initialize other classes refernce before using it

Comment: okay then, thanks. Maybe it's 'cuz of my referencing that i've been having issues transferring field variables subject to changes, forcing me to make them static. Thanks, i guess i need to read more.

Comment: @Mofe-hendyEjegi: that statement above alone is reason why you need to read up on OOPs. The **last** thing you should do is to make variables static in this situation. Do so, and your code becomes very difficult to test and extend.